# French wordings in strings.xml

Tags: android, string, android-layout

i am getting some error in strings.xml

```
<string name="grille">Une grille de sudoku correctement constituée ne peut aboutir qu'à une et une seule solution. Pour trouver les chiffres manquants, tout est une question de logique, d'observation et de rapidité ! </string>


error: Apostrophe not preceded by \ (in Une grille de sudoku correctement constituÃ©e ne peut aboutir qu'Ã  une et une seule solution. Pour trouver les chiffres manquants, tout est une question de logique, d'observation et de rapiditÃ© ! )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place `formatted="false"` as attribute to such string values with special characters.

```
<string name="grille" formatted="false">Une grille de sudoku...</string>
```

Answer (score 4):

The error itself gives the answer that you have to use `"\"` before you come across special characters such as Double-Quotes, Apostrophe.

Answer (score 1):

put the french string between "" like this :

```
<string name="grille">"Une grille de sudoku correctement constituée ne peut aboutir qu'à une et une seule solution. Pour trouver les chiffres manquants, tout est une question de logique, d'observation et de rapidité !"</string>
```